# build-impl.xml: 1054 The module has not been deployed

Tags: netbeans-8, glassfish-4.1

> Netbeans 8.1
>
> glassfish 4.1.1

After I re-install the glassfish and configure the project, clean and rebuild, it cause error: `build-impl.xml: 1054 The module has not been deployed`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I made a lot of efforts, I cannot fix it and I create a new project and copy the source files to the new project, amazingly, it can work fine. But I still cannot find out why, because the build-impl.xml are same in these two project.

So guys if you come across this problem, you can try creating a new project instead.